# Eevee Shadow clipping issue even with shadow distance

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shadows, clipping

I don't really know what's happening, when moving in certain areas, the shadow comes back, but if I look slightly away, the shadow keeps trying to disappear. I've been trying to solve this for a while, any help is appreciated.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCfPI.jpg

Comment: There is no fix for this because contact shadows are screen space so basically anything on screen casts a shadow. no amount of clipping distance can help with that, plus it doesn't matter that much because as far as I know with the gif you have provided that issue happens outside the camera bounds which means that won't appear in your render

Comment: No no, it happens even camera in view. The shadows from the light are coming back, when earlier in the camera view, there wasn't much shadow on it. Not sure what to do about this.

Comment: sadly there is nothing you can do about that in eevee, unless you combine cycles shadow pass  and the rest of eevee passes to get a eevee render with accurate shadows

Comment: https://blenderartists.org/t/combining-eevee-with-cycles-raytraced-shadows/1135504/47

this is a forum about an addon(which tries to combine shadows of cycles with the rest of eevee) that might help your situation.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Oddly though there is no download link for me to try it out.

Comment: its there on reply 60 and check reply 58 on how to use it.

Comment: I keep pressing all the download links, and all it shows is deleted file links.

Comment: Then its no good, I will bump the topic and check whether the poster is still active...